# Add two values using tryparse

Tags: parsing, double, tryparse

I have a program that calculates the area of a open field. I would like to understand how can I use the TryParse method to add two calculated values into a single text box called btnCalculate

Radiobutton when clicked, enables two textboxes E1 so that the user and input the values. These two textboxes are bounded in a groupbox.

I am wondering how can I add these two areas when button is clicked, one outside of the grpbox and the other within the grpbox using the TryParse method. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

For example:

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            double width, length;
            bool status1 = double.TryParse(this.txbxWidth.Text, out width);
            bool status2 = double.TryParse(this.txbxLength.Text, out length);
            txbxArea.Text = string.Format("{0:f}", width * length);

        if (rdb1.Checked)
        {
            double e1width, e1length;
            bool status1 = double.TryParse(this.txbxE1width.Text, out e1width);
            bool status2 = double.TryParse(this.txbxE1length.Text, out e1length);
            txbxArea.Text = string.Format("{0:f}", e1width * e1length);
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TryParse has nothing to do with the addition, etc. It is just for parsing the values.

You can add two areas as follows:

```
 private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        double width, length;
        bool status1 = double.TryParse(this.txbxWidth.Text, out width);
        bool status2 = double.TryParse(this.txbxLength.Text, out length);
        txbxArea.Text = string.Format("{0:f}", width * length);

        if (rdb1.Checked)
        {
            double e1width, e1length;
            bool status1 = double.TryParse(this.txbxE1width.Text, out e1width);
            bool status2 = double.TryParse(this.txbxE1length.Text, out e1length);
            txbxArea.Text = string.Format("{0:f}", (width * length) + (e1width * e1length));
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry to ask, how about a user only keys in rdb1 and rb2 and clicks calculate area for both, it does not show up the correct additions. Is there any way I can change my code?

Comment: That depends on the logic of your application. At first you can check which radio buttons are checked? Secondly, you can check whether the user has set the values in textboxes or left them blank? Based on these checks you can prompt the validation errors to the user.

Comment: All the radio buttons are working when checked or not, just the calculation seems not about right..if i check eg. radio button2, key in the values and get the area and the txbxarea should show the area of e1 + e2 and the main area. It goes like the pic i added above.

Comment: First of all you will need to check whether the user left main area textboxes (length and breadth) blank. You can do this by checking status1 and status2. If any of one is 0 then you can prompt the user to enter the correct values:

Comment: You can apply same validation for e1 and e2 areas, depending which radiobutton user has checked.